error TS2339: Property ‘timestamp’ does not exist in type ‘TransformableInfo’
I’m using ‘winston: “^3.3.3”’ and getting the typescript error on attribute does not exist on Type.
For the following code:
winston.format.printf(info => info.timestamp)

Winston depends on another library ‘Logform’ which has an interface ‘TransformableInfo’ and when I checked the node_modules I saw that the property was not mentioned; then on manually adding I was able to run the code; but this isn’t standard
How can we resolve it?
